# REST Service that can consume both JSON and Multipart Form

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I need to create a method in Spring MVC that can handle both JSON and Multipart Form requests.

This is my method's signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/upload_image" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void uploadImage(final ImageDTO image)
```

ImageDTO class looks as following:

```
public class ImageDTO {
  private String imageUrl;
  private Long imageId;
  private MultipartFile image;

  public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
  }

  public void setImageUrl(final String url) {
    this.imageUrl = url;
  }

  public Long getImageId() {
    return imageId;
  }

  public void setImageId(final Long imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
  }

  public MultipartFile getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  public void setImage(MultipartFile image) {
    this.image = image;
  }
}
```

So the scenario is that I need to support two scenarios:
1. Image up load from form, where the Content-Type is multipart-form (all DTO members are not null)
2. Image upload using JSON, using ONLY the imageUrl. 
In this case, the request body looks like this:

```
{
    "imageId":"1236",
    "imageUrl":"http://some.image.url",
    "image":null
}
```

The current implementation handles the multipart request well, but when sending the JSON, the ImageDTO object contains NULLs in all its members.

Is is it possible to make the same method handle both content types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To receive JSON you need to mark `ImageDTO` argument with `@RequestBody`

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/upload_image" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void uploadImage(final @RequestBody ImageDTO image)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that already, this indeed makes the JSON work, but when sending the multipart-form request it fails and the error says that multipart-form content type is not supported.

Comment: Yes, You can't directly do that.

Answer (score 1):

Had faced a similar situation, and here's what I'd come up with. Both are not-so-clean ways, but work perfectly. You need to send a **multipart request** from client:

*Note: The datatype of the variable to hold the file is `InputStream`. You need to change it accordingly*

1. This is useful in cases you are not aware of the number of files you
   are receiving in you request.

   ```
   // imports
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
   import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;

   // code flow
   // HttpServletRequest request
   final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
   final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
   List items = null;
   private Map<String, InputStream> fileMap = new HashMap<String, InputStream>();

   if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

       // get the request content and iterate through
       items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);

       if (items != null) {
           final Iterator iter = items.iterator();
           while (iter.hasNext()) {
               final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
               final String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
               final String fieldValue = item.getString();
               // this is for non-file fields
               if (item.isFormField()) {
                   switch (fieldName) {
                       case "imageId" :
                       // set inside your DTO field
                       break;

                       // do it for other fields
                   }

               } else {
                  // set the image in DTO field
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In this case, you will have to deal with fixed number of form
   fields. I had implemented in ReST method as follows:

   ```
   @Path("/upload")
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   public ResponseDTO upload(FormDataMultiPart multiPartData) {

            // non-file fields
            final String imageId = multiPartData.getField("imageId").getValue();

            // for file field    
            final FormDataBodyPart imagePart = multiPartData.getField("image");
            final ContentDisposition imageDetails= imagePart.getContentDisposition();
            final InputStream imageDoc = imagePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

            // set the retrieved content in DTO
   }
   ```

Comment: This looks like Jax-Rs not Spring MVC

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this will require that the request would always be with content-type "multipart-form". I wonder whether it is possible to make the method be able to handle both multipart form, but also json in the request.

Comment: Yes, this will require multi-part form request. You can't send file content in a JSON request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same result -  NULLs in all DTO members until I introduced the @ModelAttribute annotation. Now everything works fine, here is the working code:

**Controller method**:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
public void create(@Valid @ModelAttribute("entryForm") final EntryDTO entryDTO,
        final BindingResult validationResult) throws FormValidationError {
    validate(entryDTO, validationResult);
    entryService.save(entryDTO);
}
```

**DTO**:

```java
public class EntryDTO {

    private String phrase;

    private String translation;

    private MultipartFile imageFile;

}
```

**Form**:

```html
<form method="post" name="entryForm" action="http://localhost:8080/save"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="text" name="phrase" value="test"/> phrase</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="translation" value="тест"/> translation</p>
    <p><input type="file" name="imageFile"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Note, the form is named "entryForm" and correspondingly the @ModelAttribute("entryForm").