# Rest WS @Post consumes HttpServletRequest doesn't work

Tags: web-services, rest, post, cxf

Here's my cxf Rest WS :

```
@POST
@OPTIONS
@Path("/push")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED })
public Response push(@FormParam(value="agentId") String agentId);
```

I use it with a form :

```
<form id="form1" METHOD=POST ACTION="http://localhost:8080/uwv_interfacing-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/api/rest/callHistory/push?AppKey=536f47d5-184f-3041-850c-bcad9f3afa49">
  <input type="hidden" name="agentId" value="ofize">
  <button type="submit" name="modifier" value="1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would like to get a HttpServletRequest instead of every fields, but when i replace  "String agentId" with an HttpServletRequest it's empty, i have no fileds.
I've tried to replace the "@FormParam(value="agentId")" with "@Context" but i'm not sure about the good anotation to use.
Any idea?

Comment: what tech are you using jersey/cxf  etc to expose rest endpoint ?

Comment: I'm using cxf, sorry

Comment: Not sure, if could refer to this question to get some inputs? (uses multi-part form data)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062986/rest-service-that-can-consume-both-json-and-multipart-form/28063353#28063353

Comment: Isn't Multi-part form data made to post files in a form? I just want to post data (strings, int...)

Answer (score 0):

You can inject [MessageContext](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Contextannotations) in your class like

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;
...
@Context 
private MessageContext messageContext;
...
// in your restful method, you could do something like
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = messageContext.getHttpServletRequest();
```

Comment: I get exaclty the same with no parameters

Comment: didn't get you? What do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the HttpServletRequest using `@Context( qualified name: javax.ws.rs.core.Context)` Hence your code shouls look like something as below.

```
@POST
@OPTIONS
@Path("/push")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED })
public Response push(@FormParam(value="agentId") String agentId, final @Context HttpServletRequest request);
```